# MSO number format for Percent with 3 decimals

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, number-formatting

I need MSO Number format for exporting percent with 3 decimals to Excel from a .Net application.

I tried the code below, but it exports only 2 decimals.

```
e.Cell.Style["mso-number-format"] = @"Percent";
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something that works.

```
e.Cell.Style["mso-number-format"] = @"0\.000%";
```

Thanks.